# Replace getElementsByName with getElementsById not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function doStuff1(){
    var eml=document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value;
        msg=document.getElementsByName('message')[0];
    msg.value = eml + ' ' + msg.value;
    alert ('Message has been submitted');
    return true;  //return false to test just messagebox and updated message textarea
}
</script>
```

However, when I use `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByName` then it stops working. That is the method would not show the alert dialog.

Of course I added a `id` attribute on the same tag with the `name`, like `id="email" name="email"`

This method is called when the submit button in the form is clicked.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You may as well just look at the Console for errors and it will save you the time to write many questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementById` does not return a collection of elements, but only a single element.  `document.getElementById('email')[0].value` is a semantic error.

Remove the `[0]`s.